# Need to update a MariDB/MySQL table with information from a plaintext file depending on what character each line starts with

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, mariadb, load-data-infile

I'm going to try to keep this as simple as possible, but it's probably going to wind up a little long, mostly from examples. I've got a table that was created by importing a fixed-width file, similar to the following:

pokemon:

```
   1                       BULBASAUR
   4                      CHARMANDER
   7                        SQUIRTLE
  16                             MEW
  25                          MEWTWO
 143                         SNORLAX
 666                  MEPHISTOPHELES
```

So with something like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'pokemon' INTO TABLE pokedex
(@row)
SET number = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,2,3)),
name = TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,5,32))
;
```

I imported that data, and Bob's your uncle. The monthly update files, however, are decidedly less straightforward. They'll look something like this:

update0:

```
C 16                          PIDGEY
A 25                         PIKACHU
A150                          MEWTWO
C151                             MEW
D666                  MEPHISTOPHELES
```

That first character on each line doesn't go in the database. It denotes how the line is supposed to be handled. There's "A" for "Add," "C" for "Change," and "D" for "Delete." But it can't even be that simple.

"A" and "C" are functionally identical. If that number's not already on record, you add it. If that number is already on record, you replace it. "D," thankfully, is always just "delete."

So in the example above, the name for 16 would get updated to "PIDGEY." 25, though it's marked as an addition, would get updated to "PIKACHU" since it already exists. "MEWTWO" would get added as 150. "MEW," though marked as a change, would get added as 151 since it's not already on record. 666 would just get deleted.

What I could do, and what I'm going to do if I can't get any satisfactory responses, is set something up with python and pypyodbc to process the shit. I'm hoping, though, that there's a more elegant SQL-only way of doing it so as to minimize the number of moving parts. I'm open to and grateful for suggestions.

Comment: Any sql solution will probably be less elegant than using python or even bash.. But you might load the data into a temporary table with A/C/D in a separate column, or into 3 tables, one for each of A/C/D. And then do one delete query joining to D rows, and one insert..on duplicate key update .. select A/C rows/table

Comment: That was pretty much exactly what I ended up doing. Intermediate table, INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for A/C, DELETE WHERE for D.